# How to return a specific view based on user input in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am fairly new to MVC, but not web programming and I am having an issue with passing data values from a View to a Controller where the data values are not associated with a Model.

Scenario: I have two types of users: Student and Faculty; Basically I am trying to determine which view to return when users register on the site.

EX:

```
    public ActionResult Preregister(bool fac, bool stud)
    {

        if (stud == true)
        {
            return StudentRegister();
        }
        else if(fac == true)
        {
            return FacultyRegister();
        }
        else
        {
            return Index();
        }
    }
```

So, I want this ActionMethod called from this form:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Preregister";
}

<h2>Registration</h2>
<p>Please indicate whether you are a student or faculty.</p>
@{
    bool chkValFac = false;
    bool chkValStud = false;
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Preregister, Account"))
{
    <div class="pre-reg-container">
    <div class="checkbox-container">
        <div class="item">
            <label for="Student" style="width:70px;">Student</label>
            @Html.CheckBox("Student", chkValStud)
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <label for="Faculty" style="width:70px;">Faculty</label>
            @Html.CheckBox("Faculty", chkValFac)
        </div>
    </div>
    <input name="continue" type="submit" id="continue" value="Continue" />
</div>
}
```

In debugging, I get this error:

The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'stud' of non-nullable type 'System.Boolean' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Preregister(Boolean)' in 'Room_Booking_System.Controllers.AccountController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters

I don't understand how I can get the data from this view into the controller without posting back. I want a simple redirect based on the response. Please Help.

Thank you all!

Comment: did you solve it yet ?

Comment: 1. Use a radio button instead of a checkbox 2. Your controller will be better receiving one parameter indicating if it's a factualy or a student. Consider using an enum for that, and pass the radio selected value to the controller from the form.

Comment: It has been solved. Also, thanks for the suggestion mot. I'm considering taking it that route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind the value of checkbox directly to the parameter of action method then the parameter name of the action method should be same as the name of checkbox. So, your method signature should be look like this...

```
public ActionResult Preregister(bool faculty, bool student)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take FormCollection as input.Basically that will have all the form elements.

```
public ActionResult Preregister(FormCollection fc)
{
    bool fac = fc["Faculty"];
    bool stud = fc["Student"];
    if (stud == true)
    {
        return StudentRegister();
    }
    else if(fac == true)
    {
        return FacultyRegister();
    }
    else
    {
        return Index();
    }
}
```

Still It is always recommended practice to use some kind of model and strongly bind that with your views and use that for moving data in between view and controller

Comment: Thanks, this also worked. Are you suggesting that I may need to create a class in my model to account for this type of logic?

Comment: Yes thats usually the recommended approach